# is there any api to execute Judgment stage in spinnaker

Tags: spinnaker

I want to exectue stage in Manual Judgment via http api.

I search swagger and api docs however I couldn't find.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this in the following way:

- Request URL: `http://spin-api-url/pipelines/<pipeline-execution-id>/stages/<manual-judgement-stage-id>`
- Request Method: `Patch`
- Request Body: `{"judgmentStatus":"continue"}`

You can get the pipeline and stage execution Ids using the APIs.

- For Getting the Executions in application: **GET** `/applications/{application}/executions/search`
- For getting the execution details of pipeline: **GET** `/pipelines/{id}` Ref: [api-Pipelinecontroller-getPipelineUsingGET](https://www.spinnaker.io/reference/api/docs.html#api-Pipelinecontroller-getPipelineUsingGET)